# javascript's event handler in separate html file and javascript file

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I want to write javascript's event handler in separate html file and javascript file.
I am in trouble because it does not work if it is the method of reference site.
Sample Site : https://techacademy.jp/magazine/15062

How do I write event handlers in javascript without writing event handlers in html?
I would like to write it in a way like a sample site.

Comment: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

write code in a separate js file and add on the HTML using `<script>` file just before `</body>`

```
<script type="file/path/name.js"></script>
```

is that you are asking about?

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But it looks different.
This is written in html.
<script type = "file / path / name.js"> </ script>

As a test, I write like this.
First "test" is displayed, but it does not respond when onclick.
It seems that javascript is loading.
 
alert ("test");
document.getElementById ("text-button"). onclick = function () {
   document.getElementById ("text"). innerHTML = "Clicked!";
};

Comment: can you create a short snippet of your code using [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) so that I can help better